# How to create osx service that passes its service name to shell script?

Tags: macos, contextmenu, automator

I am creating osx service with automator to show context menu items for a file like how dropbox shows the menu below.

[image: Dropbox right click context menu]

I understand that these are not osx services but however i would to like accomplish the same thing with osx services. Hence i have created 2 osx services using automator for files and folders in Finder.app and attached a shell script action to this.

Now i could see all of my 2 services (Share with a, Share with b) in the contextual menu like below

[image]

From the shell script(actions for those services) am launching an app. I wanted to launch the app with the file path and service name as two command line args.

Any idea how to get service name of user selected service inside shell script like we get file name from the command line parameter "$@"

Comment: This doesn't seem easy.  I tried: 1) looking for an Automator predefined variable for the path and name of the current workflow, but I didn't find such a variable. 2) I tried the AppleScript command: "path to me", but that gives the path to the program running the workflow.  Can you provide what the app needs that you're launching with your services the data that it needs from your Automator action "Run Shell Script"?

Comment: Thanks Kaydell for your comment. Basically my aim is to open a browser with an URL which is different for each of the menu item. What i will be doing is that, i will launch an app / exe from the shell script by passing path to the file & service name so that the app can construct url based on the service name by reading the file details from the data base and loads the url in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

> "Basically my aim is to open a browser with an URL which is different for each of the menu item."

Something like the following AppleScript can be used to open a URL in the default web browser, using AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder" to open location "http://learnbymac.com"
```

Something like the following shell script can be used to open a URL from the shell:

```
open -a "Finder" "http://learnbymac.com"
```

Using the Finder to open URLs is better than using Safari because when you use the Finder to open URLs, you get the default browser rather than always getting Safari.

> " i will launch an app / exe from the shell script by passing path to the file & service name so that the app can construct url based on the service name by reading the file details from the data base and loads the url in the browser."

You may have to provide the name of your service in your workflow's "Run Shell Script" action when you launch your app.  This might be best anyways because then if the user changed the name of the Service, your software would still run.  I know that it would be ideal to not duplicate the name of the Service having it once in the workflow's bundle and again in your "Run Shell Script" action, but I don't know how to get the name of the currently running Service.

-- Kaydell
[kaydell@yahoo.com](http://mailto%3akaydell@yahoo.com)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I had a doubt related to multi files select. First of all do we have any control not to show service for folders and multi select. If not, How can we determine that the service is kicked in because of multiple files select click. I noticed that $@ is giving path to only one file.

Comment: Sorry. I could see the shell script is called with all files as command line args. Anyways, is there anyway we can show the service entry only for files but not for folders?

Comment: Since you're developing an .app, it seems like the best thing to do would be to build the Services into your app.  Here's a link to a Mac Programming Wiki that I just started.  http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=Services_Menu What you should look at is down a the bottom of this page, there is a link to a project called "SimpleService" from Apple.  It should get you started with building services into apps using Xcode.

Comment: "First of all do we have any control not to show service for folders and multi select?" You may need to use a UTI besides "public.item" which allows both files and folders to be selected.  Another idea is to let files and folders be selected and start the Service and have the Service filter out folders, and then if there are zero items left to process, alert the user.  Something like that.

Comment: "I noticed that $@ is giving path to only one file"  Will you give me a link to documentation on what $@ is supposed to do?

Comment: I don't have any explicit control in not showing service for folders and multi select. In the worst case, i can alert the user once they selected the service based on the path of the file and number of command line args to the shell script.

Comment: When i drag "Run Shell Script" as an action item to the service in Automator. There we have an option for the shell script to pass input (to stdin / as arguments). When you select "as arguments" option there you can find $@ preloaded script.